# C++: How to jump to the next immediate line when reading a file?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm working on a simple two-pass assembler for the Nand To Tetris course, and everything works just fine except for reading lines. I use a getline() with a delimiter so it stops extracting data when it reaches a comment. However, instead of stop reading and going to the next line when encountering the '/' delimiter:

```
                       Stopped reading here
                               || 
                               \/ 
                     Skip -> 1 / Almost a comment
Jumped to the second line -> 2
                             3 @NOT_A_COMMENT
```

it does:

```
        Jumped here & extracted the rest of the line
                ||              ||
                \/              \/
From here -> 1 / Almost a comment
             2
             3 @NOT_A_COMMENT
```

So I was wondering how I could do what I showed in the first example.

Here is my code as of now:

```
while(getline(asmFile, label, '/')){
    if(label[0] == '@' || isalpha(label[0]))
        instructionNum++;

    else if(label[0] == '(')
        symbolsMap.emplace(label.substr(1, label.find_first_of(')')-1), convertToBinary(to_string(instructionNum+1)));
}
```

Comment: When I found the terminating condition and wanted to bail out on the line early I'd do another `getline`, but this with the default newline delimiter. Another possibility is to always read the whole line into a `string`, pop the `string` into a `stringstream` and parse the `stringstream`. If you want to exit early, there's nothing more you have to do.

Comment: Maybe you could just read the whole line and remove the comment after.

Comment: BTW if your `getline` returns an empty string from a blank line, you have undefined behaviour when you try this `label[0]`. You should really check the `label` is not empty.

Comment: If you want to seek to the line beginnings, you should read the file a line at a time, then store the position after reading the line.  Store these into a vector.  You can then index into the vector to find the file position of the beginning of a line.  This is all because most text files are not fixed length records.  The position of fixed length records can easily be found by using arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to do achieve this is to process it line by line and then remove the comment as suggested by @Galik.

you can add a simple function which removes comment from the given line.

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::string RemoveComment(std::string line, T&& c) {
  const auto pos = line.find(c);
  if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    line = line.substr(0, pos);
  }
  return line;
}
```

```cpp
while(getline(asmFile, label)){
    label = RemoveComment(label,'/');

    // Note: you might want to continue in case of empty string
    if(lable.empty()) continue;

    // do your magic
}
```

---

another method which I can think of is to use [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

eg. Input file

```
some text.
/ comment.
some other text.
```

code:

```cpp
while(getline(asmFile, label, '/')){
    // for given input label will contain "some text."
    // and position indicator will point to next char after delim '/'.
   
    /* process label */  

    // skip till end of line 
     asmFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: I did your first suggestion and it worked perfectly. I liked the ignore idea more since it looks cleaner. However, when I implemented it, after reading past a few newlines it would extract multiple lines as one entire line (all their respective \n included). It works just fine with your example input, but for some reason, it doesn't with my files. I even checked that all lines in the files have \n and they do, which confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: can you provide a minimal input file? in which you are observing the issue

Comment: @GABRIELALOPEZ-LUGO if you are satisfied with the answer to feel free to accept this answer and close